# Action between massive selection in InputBox

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting string array from InputBox with:

```
Set productName = Application.InputBox("Select products from list:", _
  "Our dialog", , , , , , 8)
```

I want to color the cells, which I have chosen, after each choice. 
For example, I want to select 10 cells (with one `InputBox` action). 
I choose one (on this step I want to color this cell, to remember, that I have already chosen it), then press CTRL , choose second (color the cell), choose third (color the cell) etc.

Is it possible to make this with VBA?

Comment: You can choose all cells and colorize them in the end.

Comment: I need to colorize after each selection, because i make selection from very big list and it's easy to confuse, what i have chosen and what - no

Comment: The cells you choose get highlighted already, is that not enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question *"Is it possible to make this with VBA"* is: No it is not possible.

You cannot do this with only *one* `InputBox` but you can keep asking for a range selection until the user presses cancel.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ColorizeSelections()
    Dim SelRange As Range
    Dim ColorRange As Range

    Do
        On Error Goto CANCEL_LOOP 'next line throws error if cancel is pressed
        Set ColorRange = Application.InputBox("Select products from list:", "Our dialog", , , , , , 8)
        On Error GoTo 0 'always re-activate error reporting!!!

        ColorRange.Interior.Color = vbGreen 'color new selected range

        'remember all selected ranges in SelRange
        If SelRange Is Nothing Then
            Set SelRange = ColorRange
        Else
            Set SelRange = Union(SelRange, ColorRange)
        End If

        SelRange.Select 'select all previously selected ranges that were already colored.
    Loop
CANCEL_LOOP:
    'other stuff goes here
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank u. I understand how to make it with lot of InputBoxes, but hoped, that it's possible with one.

Comment: @AlexeyC Then the answer to your question is: No it is not possible. • I improved my answer so you can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub ran()
    Dim stc As Range
    Dim ytd As String
    Do
        On Error GoTo cc
        Set stc = Application.InputBox("Selection", "Select range", Type:=8)

        Dim cell As Range
        stc.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
    Loop
cc:
    MsgBox ("Done")
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Also `Dim cell As Range` and `Dim ytd As String` are pretty useless.

Comment: Ty.  I understand how to make it with lot of InputBoxes, but hoped, that it's possible with one.